# Alternative terminal emulation for Google Cloud browser SSH login?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, terminal

Can the Google Cloud SSH browser support any other character sets besides ASCII?

I go into my Dashboard, then click on SSH.

[image]

After that, the CLI "gui" uses extended ASCII. Instead of extended ASCII lines being used, it seems like only US7ASCII is being used. Is there a way to change the character set or terminal emulation used by default?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternative methods to SSH your instance, like PuTTY

> https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#thirdpartytools

And you can use the Cloud Shell for SSH running this command

```
gcloud compute ssh --project [PROJECT_ID] --zone [ZONE] [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

Which character encoding are your OS using? You can check it running the command `locale` if this looks fine try commenting out `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in the local `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3218/ssh-and-character-encoding